# Jupyter notebook kernel dies when running gym env.render()

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

EDIT: When i remove `render_mode="rgb_array"` it works fine. But this obviously is not a real solution.

I am trying to run a render of a game in Jupyter notebook but each time i run it i get a pop up saying `Python 3.7 crashed` and the kernel has died.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import gym
from gym.envs.registration import register
from IPython.display import clear_output

try:
    register(
        id='FrozenLakeNotSlippery-v0', #Name this whatever you want
        entry_point='gym.envs.toy_text:FrozenLakeEnv',
        kwargs={'map_name' : '4x4', 'is_slippery': False},
        max_episode_steps=100,
        reward_threshold=0.78, # optimum = .8196
    ) 
except: 
    print("Already Registered")
    
env = gym.make("FrozenLakeNotSlippery-v0",render_mode='rgb_array')
env.reset()
for step in range(5):
    env.render()
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(observation)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    if terminated:
        env.reset()
    
env.close()
```

Above is the code I have. Its very straight forward and seems to be a known issue, though I haven't seen anyone have any solutions.

I have tried uninstalling and then re-installing the following packages with pip install:

- ipykernel
- ipython
- jupyter_client
- jupyter_core
- traitlets
- ipython_genutils
  But i still have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ave found the issue: if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/70ca46a9685de333493722ee74d0cd51782b2b44/gym/envs/toy_text/frozen_lake.py#L58) for `frozen_lake`, it only accepts a `render_mode` of `'human'` & `'ansi'`:

```
metadata = {'render.modes': ['human', 'ansi']}
```

so a `render_mode="rgb_array"`, as in my case above, will produce an error.